# FCM - When app is killed/in background, app receives notification but does not play the notification sound

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated FCM in android. Everything is working fine but when my app is in background, it is receiving the notification but it is not playing the notification sound.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification_icon" />
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/notification_icon_background" />
```

I have added this above code in Android.manifest inside application tag.
Can you please help me?

Comment: you need to use DATA payload instead of notification

Comment: @Divyesh can you please post an answer or a link as a reference.?

Comment: search for notification vs data payload firebase notification. you get links

Comment: Hi. Do post your sample payload and your Android side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel all of the above answers are helpful, but if you need it from server end developed with java you need to do this:

```
JSONArray registration_ids = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(data));
    message.put("registration_ids", registration_ids);
    message.put("priority", "high");
JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
    notification.put("title", "Happy Googling");
    notification.put("body", "A Sinha");
    notification.put("sound","default");
    message.put("notification", notification);
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(message.toString(), "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 1):

use field like this in payload.

```
$fields=array('to'=>fdfdfdfdsfdsdfdfdsfdsfdfdsfd" ,'notification'=>array('title'=>'mytitle','body'=>$title,'click_action'=>'abc','icon'=>'ic_stat_final','sound'=>'default','color'=>'#00aff0'),'data'=>array('ghmid'=>$hgmid,'page'=>$page));
```

Comment: why minus  i pasted my working code  you can change acording you

Comment: i used like it not exactly

Comment: I haven't given a minus point... Though from your post I could get an idea as to how to go about... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please pass following of the data from your server :

```
{
    "to" : "deviceToken",

    "notification" : {
      "body" : "Pass body here",
      "title" : "Title For Notification",
      "icon" : " icon ",
      "sound" : "notification sound here"
    }
  }
```

You can also pass in sound section as "default"